# Why cannot render HTML with ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have seen online plenty of examples and tests using React and typescript where they issue something like this:

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
 <h1>Hello world!!</h1>, //or any other valid html snippet
 document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

However, when I try to reproduce those multiple examples in my machine, I get, first a highlight error from VS code, and then when I try to bundle I get this error:

> TS2686: 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a
>   module. Consider adding an import instead.

If instead of putting the HTML as argument of the function I write a `my SimpleComponent.render()`, the bundle will be produced without errors.

What is wrong with that code snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add `import * as React from 'react'`. `<h1>` is React component (`React.createClass('h1')` after transpile JSX to JavaScript), but you have imported only `ReactDOM`.

Comment: ...because once the JSX is transpiled, that `<h1>Hello world!!</h1>` becomes `React.createElement("h1", /*...*/);`.

Comment: Great! that worked. Do you know the reason why needs that reference if the html is hardcoded there? It does not make sense to me.

Comment: You no need to reference it. This still works but as HTMLElement is wrong. This is valid ReactDOM.render(
 <h1>Hello world!!</h1>,
 document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: @HemadriDasari - The OP is using TypeScript. The `as HTMLElement` is correct.

Comment: Ok sorry I don’t no typescript